# How to format java Date

Tags: java, spring, parsing, date-format

I am working on a Spring project and I have to search Documents by date of upload. So when I pass my date as parameter of a method in DAO layer it's received like: `Thu Jun 06 00:03:49 WEST 2013`. And I want to format that to : `2013-06-06`

I have used this code to do that but it returns `06/06/13` and other constants of DateFormat (like DateFormat.MEDIUM, ...) do not return what I am waiting for.

```
DateFormat shortDf = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);       
System.out.println(shortDf.format(new Date())); // return 06/06/13 it's short
```

I have also tried the SimpleDateFormat like that:

```
public static Date parseDate(String date, String format)throws ParseException {
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format,Locale.ENGLISH);
return formatter.parse(date);
}
```

But it is still throwing a parsing Exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jun 06 00:23:33 WEST 2013"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
at TestApp.main(TestApp.java:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to format a date to your own format like `2013-06-06`, SimpleDateFormatter is a common solution. But what went wrong in your code is that you have a wrong return type for a formatted date. Here's the example:

```
Date d=new Date();
String formattedDate=format(d);

System.out.println("This is your date: "+formattedDate);  

public String format(String date){
  SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  return sdf.format(date);
}
```

To format a date into your own format, use sdf.format, not sdf.parse.
sdf.parse is used to convert String to Date, while sdf.format used to convert Date to String in a specified format.

sdf.parse returns Date, sdf.format returns String.

Comment: Yes I have find this solution like you have described

Comment: pPlease mark this thread as answered if you feel it answers your question,  so people know that there's a solution found in this thread :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work in your case:

```
    DateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try {
        Date date = sourceFormat.parse("Thu Jun 06 00:23:33 WEST 2013");
        String formatted = targetFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

First, you need to parse the date with the correct format and locale (change `Locale.US` to whatever suits you). The exception you were getting is caused by an incorrect parse format or missing locale.

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz  yyyy
Thu Jun 06 00:23:33 WEST 2013
```

And then format the result using this formatting string:

```
yyyy-MM-dd
2013-06-06
```

([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

Comment: You are right dears I have to use format method not the pare one

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    System.out.println("Formated date: " + formatter.format(currentDate)); // returns 2013/06/06 like waited


Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Just keep in mind that `SimpleDateFormat` class is not thread safe and causes issues in multi-threaded environments if not used properly which means you must be really careful to use it in Spring it is  multi-threaded env.

Why it is not thread-safe?

The `SimpleDateFormat` class mutates its internal state for formatting and parsing dates. That’s why it results issues when multiple threads use the same instance of SimpleDateFormat concurrently.

How to use SimpleDateFormat in a multi-threaded environment?

There are two options -

- Create a new instance of `SimpleDateFormat` for each thread.
- Synchronize concurrent access by multiple threads with a synchronized keyword or a lock.

Comment: Or the best option: use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I can get:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Comment: +1 This `DateFormat` will convert the proposed `String` in a `Date`, just ensure to pass a correct Locale to recognize days and month.